# How to redirect twice in php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a script in php or javascript that will redirect the user to a page,wait x seconds and then redirect to another site.
Let's see an example

1. User acces www.abcdefg.com/Redirect.php
2. User is redirected to another site A
3. Script is waiting x seconds
4. User si automatically redireced to site B

Note: All these stuff must be made throught a single script Redirect.php
It musn't open new tabs,everything is running on one window.

What i know.
I gave found that the header tag can be use to redirect you to someting.But when we are redirected ,we cancel the script execution,because we acces another site.

So how can I do a l duble redirect throught a site??
Thank you verry much and sorry for my bad englesh.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

Comment: Once you've redirected away from a page you control, that's it ; you've lost control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first page you should redirect to a special "redirect.php" page like that:

```
header('location: redirect.php?to=http://www.newsite.com');
```

This will take you to `http://www.yoursite.com/redirect.php?to=http://www.newsite.com`

And then your "redirect.php" page could be:

```
header('location: ' + $_GET['to']);
```